# uPortal deploy-ear Build Failure - error while parsing schema(s).location

Tags: maven, jaxb, web-deployment, portal, build-error

I am trying to deploy a uPortal 4.0.6 instance to a dev server environment. I am new to this company and there is little to no documentation on how the customizations that have been made in the past were configured.

After doing a **ant clean deploy-ear** command this morning I got the following Build Failure stack trace:

```
[artifact:mvn] **[ERROR] Error while parsing schema(s).Location [ jar:file:/C:/Use
rs/rfountain/.m2/repository/org/jasig/portal/uportal-search-api/4.0.6-SNAPSHOT
/uportal-search-api-4.0.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/META-INF/sun-jaxb.episode{11,93}].
[artifact:mvn] com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2: SCD "x-schema::tns" didnt matc
h any schema component**
[artifact:mvn]  at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.SCDBasedBindingSet.repo
rtError(SCDBasedBindingSet.java:256)
[artifact:mvn]  at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.SCDBasedBindingSet.repo
rtError(SCDBasedBindingSet.java:250)
[artifact:mvn]  at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.SCDBasedBindingSet.acce
ss$100(SCDBasedBindingSet.java:78)
[artifact:mvn]  at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.SCDBasedBindingSet$Targ
et.apply(SCDBasedBindingSet.java:158)
[artifact:mvn]  at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.SCDBasedBindingSet$Targ
et.applyAll(SCDBasedBindingSet.java:142)
[artifact:mvn]  at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.SCDBasedBindingSet$Targ  
et.access$700(SCDBasedBindingSet.java:86)
[artifact:mvn]  at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.SCDBasedBindingSet.appl
y(SCDBasedBindingSet.java:241)
[artifact:mvn]  at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.createXSOM(ModelLoader.java:535
)
[artifact:mvn]  at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.loadXMLSchema(ModelLoader.java:
379)
```

I have spent a few hours already "chasing goasts" and can't seem to find the source of the problem.

The environment is a Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard. 
I'm running maven 2.2.1, Java 1.6.0_25, and ant 1.8.3

I can provide any further details as requested. At this point, I'm not sure what would help.

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue by using the short and simple work around described here: [uportal build errors](http://www.mail-archive.com/uportal-dev@lists.ja-sig.org/msg03632.html)